# How to set data field cell value based on value match in another field (pandas)?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with date and value fields. I need to change the value in a field if the date matches. Here is a dataset:

```
        date        confirmed   deaths  

701     2020-03-02  NaN         NaN 
702     2020-03-03  NaN         NaN 
703     2020-03-04  NaN         NaN 
704     2020-03-05  NaN         NaN 
705     2020-03-06  NaN         NaN
```

Specially made a slice of the data to make it clearer. I want to enter the value `2` for the date `2020-03-04` in the `deaths` field. How can I do this? Based exactly on the `date` field.

At the output I want to get this:

```
        date        confirmed   deaths  

701     2020-03-02  NaN         NaN 
702     2020-03-03  NaN         NaN 
703     2020-03-04  NaN         2
704     2020-03-05  NaN         NaN 
705     2020-03-06  NaN         NaN
```

I tried several ways but it didn't work for some reason. Can you help?

Comment: `df.loc[df['date'].eq('2020-03-04'), 'deaths'] = 2`

Comment: @mozway, Hello again. I'm trying to add the data of the first infected to a dataset based on news data. I get with error  ```int' object has no attribute 'loc'```(  In the dataset itself, in this record field, there is a float, but even with ``` = 2.0 ``` i get ```'float' object has no attribute 'loc'```

Comment: Looks like you assigned a float to `df` ;)

Comment: @mozway, And how can I solve it?

Comment: don't do the mistake on the first place ;) Please provide fully reproducible code, it just looks like you are having typos or basic errors here.